# How to filter a list with index

Tags: python

```
ListA = ['Sehingga 30 Ogos 2021: Jumlah kes COVID-19 yang dilaporkan adalah 19,268 kes (1,725,357 kes).\nPecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):\nSelangor - 3,567 (599,624)\nWPKL - 672 (172,236)\nSabah - 2,310 (145,249)\nJohor - 2,265 (136,488)\nSarawak - 2,028 (114,273)\nKedah - 2,084 (97,100)\nNegeri Sembilan - 269 (91,261)\nPulau Pinang - 1,780 (84,759)\nKelantan - 1,308 (76,047)\nPerak - 1,144 (66,889)\nMelaka - 395 (48,141)\nPahang - 788 (43,335)\nTerengganu - 544 (32,884)\nWP Labuan - 2 (9,808)\nWP Putrajaya - 41 (5,373)\nPerlis - 71 (1,890)\nREAD MORE...']
```

Expected output:

```
Sehingga 30 Ogos 2021: Jumlah kes COVID-19 yang dilaporkan adalah 19,268 kes (1,725,357 kes).

Pecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):

Selangor - 3,567 (599,624)
WPKL - 672 (172,236)
Sabah - 2,310 (145,249)
Johor - 2,265 (136,488)
Sarawak - 2,028 (114,273)
Kedah - 2,084 (97,100)
Negeri Sembilan - 269 (91,261)
Pulau Pinang - 1,780 (84,759)
Kelantan - 1,308 (76,047)
Perak - 1,144 (66,889)
Melaka - 395 (48,141)
Pahang - 788 (43,335)
Terengganu - 544 (32,884)
WP Labuan - 2 (9,808)
WP Putrajaya - 41 (5,373)
Perlis - 71 (1,890)
```

and each of the state have their own index, for example:

```
index[0] = Selangor - 3,567 (599,624)
index[1] = WPKL - 672 (172,236)
index[2] = Sabah - 2,310 (145,249)
and so on..
```

I tried with regex function:

```
out = []
for v in listView:
    regex_list = re.findall(r"^(.*?\(.*?\))\n", v.replace('.\n\n', '\n').replace('.', ':'), flags=re.M)
    for g in regex_list:
        out.append(g.split(":")[0])
```

But some index is not accurate, for example: when I call `index[2]` it couldn't return me `Sabah - 2,310 (145,249)` but return me `Johor - 2,265 (136,488)` instead

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing the input along with the output.

Comment: I don't think that you need regex here at all. `out = [s.split(":", 1)[0] for v in ListA for s in v.splitlines() if s]`

Comment: I just update my question

Comment: @johnny2000, how do you get this data? Do you scrape it on some website?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, Im doing a a small research on web scraping

Comment: @johnny2000, could you add to the question sample of web page where this info exists or link to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the below is what you are looking for

```
data = 'Sehingga 30 Ogos 2021: Jumlah kes COVID-19 yang dilaporkan adalah 19,268 kes (1,725,357 kes).\nPecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):\nSelangor - 3,567 (599,624)\nWPKL - 672 (172,236)\nSabah - 2,310 (145,249)\nJohor - 2,265 (136,488)\nSarawak - 2,028 (114,273)\nKedah - 2,084 (97,100)\nNegeri Sembilan - 269 (91,261)\nPulau Pinang - 1,780 (84,759)\nKelantan - 1,308 (76,047)\nPerak - 1,144 (66,889)\nMelaka - 395 (48,141)\nPahang - 788 (43,335)\nTerengganu - 544 (32,884)\nWP Labuan - 2 (9,808)\nWP Putrajaya - 41 (5,373)\nPerlis - 71 (1,890)\nREAD MORE...'
items = data.split('\n')
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

output

```
Sehingga 30 Ogos 2021: Jumlah kes COVID-19 yang dilaporkan adalah 19,268 kes (1,725,357 kes).
Pecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):
Selangor - 3,567 (599,624)
WPKL - 672 (172,236)
Sabah - 2,310 (145,249)
Johor - 2,265 (136,488)
Sarawak - 2,028 (114,273)
Kedah - 2,084 (97,100)
Negeri Sembilan - 269 (91,261)
Pulau Pinang - 1,780 (84,759)
Kelantan - 1,308 (76,047)
Perak - 1,144 (66,889)
Melaka - 395 (48,141)
Pahang - 788 (43,335)
Terengganu - 544 (32,884)
WP Labuan - 2 (9,808)
WP Putrajaya - 41 (5,373)
Perlis - 71 (1,890)
READ MORE...
```

Comment: There's [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). And result could contain empty strings, so will be good to filter them.